# Error: No Mount Point For (/) defined

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I am trying to get the NetBeans IDE to work with the g++ compiler.  I am downloading from cygwin.  I've tried googling the problem and I have tried many things to get C++ to work on NetBeans.  I can't figure out the magic trick so I am asking for your help.

I have two problems, I don't know if these problems are related to each other.
Problem one:  I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Gbm.png) when I try to run my small program.
Problem Two:I get a `"Cannot find include file <iostream>".`  When I hold ctrl and hover over the include directory my compiler says `Unresolved directive #include<iostream>`

I followed [this NetBeans Guide](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html) on how to install and configure C++ support.  Following those directions I had received the two errors above.

Here is what my environment variable looks like: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PE5S.png)
Here is what the C/C++ build tools look like for NetBeans: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXEjV.png)
Here is the code I am trying to run; [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTxuc.png)

At the moment I am installing everything from the development tab in the cygwin setup program.

- I've tried messing with different settings but the two problems were still there.
- I've tried running NetBeans in admin mode but the two problems were still there
- I've tried un-installing cygwin and installing minGW.  That fixes problem number one, but the there is no output when the program runs.
- I've tried adding C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.8.2\include\c++ to the "Include Directories and Headers" in Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler.  This resolved iostream, but the other directives under iostream had the same problem, that the other include files could not be found.

I've been at this problem for five hours or so.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I am running:
Windows 7 64 bit
NetBeans 7.4

If you need anything else, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that my firewall, comodo firewall, was sand boxing the files that needed to run.  After disabling the sand boxing feature NetBeans ran fine.